# Section of a circle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I need some help with some of my homework, I can't figure it out.

I have a radius on a circle and a height from the circle to the chord.

I found this formula
$$
h=r \left(1-\cos \frac{v}{2} \right)
$$
And isolated it to
$$
v = \arccos \left( \frac{h/r -1}{2}\right)
$$
Not sure if that's correct. Then I input it in this formula
$$
A=r^2((\pi v)/360-(\sin v)/2)
$$
I have tried with a radius of 1000 and a height from the circle to the chord of 1000.

But it gives a wrong result.

Comment: What is given, what do you search for? So given: radius r, and distance to (some) chord h. What is $v$?

Comment: I want to find the areal, of the circle section. R=1000, Distinace to chord=1000. Then i calculate v in the first formula.

Comment: When the radius and distance to the chord is exactly the same, it should be the half of the circle. But it gives a wrong result, i am not sure whetever i mixup radians and degress, or i isolated it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your solution is incorrect.  You have the 2 factor in the wrong place.  the correct solution is:

```
                    v=2arccos((1-h/r)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But can you explain me how v, can be 180 degress. Isn't it a triangle like on this image http://matb1htx.systime.dk/fileadmin/indhold/ISBNXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Kapitel_3/fig52.png

Comment: In your example, the height to the chord is equal to the radius.  Therefore the chord becomes a diameter and the angle subtended by a diameter is 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that is correct: 
$v=2\arccos(1-\frac{h}{r})$

And this is how we get it:

$\cos(\frac{v}{2}) = \frac{r-h}{r}$
$\cos(\frac{v}{2}) = 1-\frac{h}{r}$
$\frac{v}{2} = \arccos(1-\frac{h}{r})$
$v=2\arccos(1-\frac{h}{r})$

See this [homework help resource](http://www.homeworkmarket.com/homework-help) for more.